# Remove duplicates from an array of objects but concatenate duplicate key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've an array of objects that looks like this (a sample) -

```
let arrTable = [
{ tableName: "name 1", tableDesc:"desc 1", tableFooter:"footer 1"},
{ tableName: "name 2", tableDesc:"desc 2", tableFooter:"footer 2"},
{ tableName: "name 1", tableDesc:"desc 1", tableFooter:"footer 3"},
{ tableName: "name 3", tableDesc:"desc 3", tableFooter:"footer 4"},
{ tableName: "name 4", tableDesc:"desc 4", tableFooter:"footer 5"},
{ tableName: "name 5", tableDesc:"desc 5", tableFooter:"footer 6"},
{ tableName: "name 6", tableDesc:"desc 6", tableFooter:"footer 7"},
];
```

I want to remove duplicates with the same **tableName** but concatenate the **tableFooter** for those duplicates in the one that won't be removed.

For example, the expected array of objects should be -

```
    let newTable = [
    { tableName: "name 1", tableDesc:"desc 1", tableFooter:"footer 1 footer 3"},
    { tableName: "name 2", tableDesc:"desc 2", tableFooter:"footer 2"},
    { tableName: "name 3", tableDesc:"desc 3", tableFooter:"footer 4"},
    { tableName: "name 4", tableDesc:"desc 4", tableFooter:"footer 5"},
    { tableName: "name 5", tableDesc:"desc 5", tableFooter:"footer 6"},
    { tableName: "name 6", tableDesc:"desc 6", tableFooter:"footer 7"},
    ];
```

I've checked other questions on how to remove duplicates but is there an easier way to concatenate a key without having to run a for loop and check for same tableName and create a new key that saves the tableFooter in one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using `Array.reduce()` to get the desired output.

We create an object with a property for each tableName, and if it already exists we append the tableFooter value.

```js
let arrTable = [
{ tableName: "name 1", tableDesc:"desc 1", tableFooter:"footer 1"},
{ tableName: "name 2", tableDesc:"desc 2", tableFooter:"footer 2"},
{ tableName: "name 1", tableDesc:"desc 1", tableFooter:"footer 3"},
{ tableName: "name 3", tableDesc:"desc 3", tableFooter:"footer 4"},
{ tableName: "name 4", tableDesc:"desc 4", tableFooter:"footer 5"},
{ tableName: "name 5", tableDesc:"desc 5", tableFooter:"footer 6"},
{ tableName: "name 6", tableDesc:"desc 6", tableFooter:"footer 7"},
];

let newTable = Object.values(arrTable.reduce((acc, { tableName, tableFooter, ...rest}) => { 
    if (!acc[tableName]) {
        acc[tableName] = { tableName, ...rest, tableFooter};
    } else {
        acc[tableName].tableFooter += ` ${tableFooter}`;
    }
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log(newTable)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Keep in mind .reduce() is O(n^2).

Comment: I'm not sure that is accurate in this case, we're looping through the the arrTable array once, hence this will be O(n).

Comment: This case looks fine, I'm just mentioning worst case. Good note though ^^

Comment: Ah, yes indeed, if we stuck an Array.find() in the loop it would be O(n^2) alright.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked great!

Answer (score 2):

You need another array where you can push the non-duplicate items while modifying the duplicates.

This seems to work:

```js
let arrTable = [
  { tableName: "name 1", tableDesc:"desc 1", tableFooter:"footer 1"},
  { tableName: "name 2", tableDesc:"desc 2", tableFooter:"footer 2"},
  { tableName: "name 1", tableDesc:"desc 1", tableFooter:"footer 3"},
  { tableName: "name 3", tableDesc:"desc 3", tableFooter:"footer 4"},
  { tableName: "name 4", tableDesc:"desc 4", tableFooter:"footer 5"},
  { tableName: "name 5", tableDesc:"desc 5", tableFooter:"footer 6"},
  { tableName: "name 6", tableDesc:"desc 6", tableFooter:"footer 7"},
];


let result = [];

arrTable.forEach((entry) => {
  // if the entry already exists, we just update its footer...
  // if you still need the original, make sure to make a copy of the entry here
  let existingEntry = result.find((e) => entry.tableName === e.tableName);
  if (existingEntry) {
    existingEntry.tableFooter += entry.tableFooter;
  } else {
    // new entries are added as they are
    result.push(entry);
  }
});

console.log('RESULT', result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!